# Convergence of $(x_n)_{n\in N} = (\frac{1}{n})_{n\in N}$ in different topologies

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with a range of different topologies: discrete; indistcrete, Euclidean, cofinite, cocountable and lower limit. Suppose we have a sequence of real numbers given by $(x_n)_{n\in N} = (\frac{1}{n})_{n\in N}$. I'm trying to solve these questions on convergence in these different topologies: Does this sequence converge? If yes, to what points in $\mathbb{R}$?

I've found the following solutions:

- Discrete: does not converge;
- Indiscrete: convergence to all $x \in \mathbb{R}$;
- Euclidean: converges to $0$;
- Cofinite: convergence to all $x \in \mathbb{R}$;
- Cocountable: does not converge;
- Lower limit: converges to $0$.

Are these results correct? I am not looking for a full proof or explanation in each case, as I think I am capable writing it out. Just wondering if my rough intuition is correct :)

Comment: All the answers seem correct to me. :)

Comment: @SangchulLee great! thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.